# How to implement n-body simulation with pymunk?

Tags: python, pygame, physics-engine, pymunk

I'm new with pymunk and I would like to implement a n-body simulation (in 2D) like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otIGNTFJwpU&feature=youtu.be

I already know how to create the space, shapes and the rendering with pygame. My question: **is there a way to add gravitation forces between shapes in pymunk?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you could show what you have tried, or describe the research you have done? How have you established that this CANNOT be done by pymunk?

Comment: Ok so what I did already is to create the space with the bodies. Now I need to implement gravitation forces between every pairs of bodies. My first guess was to use `pymunk.constraint` which *describes how two bodies interact with each other*. However this class contains only `["PinJoint", "SlideJoint", "PivotJoint", "GrooveJoint", "DampedSpring", "DampedRotarySpring", "RotaryLimitJoint", "RatchetJoint", "GearJoint", "SimpleMotor"]` and it does not look obvious to tweak of these to reproduce gravitation force.

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include the code you already have (use 4 spaces to format as code). The method you'll probably want to use is a double for-loop on the bodies in your system. Then use [the inverse square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity#Newton.27s_theory_of_gravitation) to work out the magnitude and use [apply_force_at_local_point](http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.Body.apply_force_at_local_point) on the centre of the object.

Comment: Although it is in C, there is a Chipmunk (which Pymunk wraps) demo called "Planet" that might be able to help you. You can find it at the Chipmunk github page [here](https://github.com/mayoff/Chipmunk-Physics/tree/master/Demo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to do it directly in pymunk. The easiest is probably to calculate it yourself. Loop the bodies and for each body make a space query to find nearby bodies. Calculate the resulting gravity and use apply impulse.

(Possibly its possible to emualte with one of the constraints, for example the pin joint or damped spring.. but that will require some thinking and experimenting to find out if its possible and looks good)

Comment: Hi Viblo, thank you for your answer. Eventually I went into the Chipmunk source code and made a copy of `cpDampedSpring` were I modified `apply_impulse()` (see my fork [here](https://github.com/rronan/pymunk/blob/master/chipmunk_src/src/cpGravitation.c)).

As I updated the python wrapper too, I can now add "Gravitation" constraints between objects and I don't need to do the loop by myself.
It seems to work well, but if you have ideas to make it better please let me know.

And thanks for pymunk.

Comment: Interesting! Maybe you could make a PR against the main Chipmunk repo (https://github.com/slembcke/Chipmunk2D) in case this constraint would be useful for more people.